# Why is my Webpack not working for CSS Modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, css-modules, sass-loader

I am trying to use CSS Modules to style my react components. I have sass-loader configured in my webpack build, however, the stylings do not get applied to my components. Please see below for a component example and my webpack config. Is there something I am doing wrong in webpack that is causing this issue or something I am doing wrong in how I am writing my component? Thanks!

**sampleComponent.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './sampleComponent.scss';

const SampleComponent = (
    <p className={styles.description}>This is some text</p>
);

export default SampleComponent;
```

**sampleComponent.scss:**

```
.description {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

**webpack.common.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

const config = {
  entry: [
    "babel-polyfill",
    `${SRC_DIR}/app/index.js`,
    `${SRC_DIR}/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`,
    `${SRC_DIR}/app/components/index.scss`,
    "font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css",
    "rc-time-picker/assets/index.css",
    "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css",
    "@trendmicro/react-toggle-switch/dist/react-toggle-switch.css",
  ],
  output: {
    path: `${DIST_DIR}/app/`,
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/app/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        options: {
          failOnWarning: false,
          failOnError: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'stage-2']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: ['file-loader?context=src/images&name=images/[path][name].[ext]', {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          query: {
            mozjpeg: {
              progressive: true,
            },
            gifsicle: {
              interlaced: false,
            },
            optipng: {
              optimizationLevel: 7,
            },
            pngquant: {
              quality: '75-90',
              speed: 3,
            },
          },
        }],
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        include: __dirname,
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        // loader: "url?limit=10000"
        use: "url-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "application.css"
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.INTERNAL': JSON.stringify(process.env.INTERNAL),
    }),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
import React from 'react';
import './sampleComponent.scss';

const SampleComponent = (
    <p className="description">This is some text</p>
);

export default SampleComponent;
```